# WinSock recv() end of message

Tags: c++, winsock, network-protocols

Consider the following scenario:

I have a server and a client, and they communicate in a custom defined application protocol.
A typical conversation is like this: (Assuming a connection between the two)

1. Client sends message to server, and waits for acknowledgment (don't
   confuse with TCP) that it's message has been processed
2. Server parses the message and as soon as it reached the end it sends
   an acknowledgment back to the client that it has processed it's
   message
3. Client gets the acknowledgment and can now freely send another
   message and wait again for an acknowledgment etc etc.

I have come to a problem implementing this. I am looping `recv()` parsing the message but as soon as recv has nothing more to return it **blocks**, and my code can't proceed to argue that I've received the whole message so that it sends an acknowledgment.

I've managed to somehow come around this by sending a message size in the header of the message and counting each time whether I've read as many bytes as the message size, but this is not ideal; what if the client machine bugged and it sent an incorrect size?

Also, I've read in another question that this whole acknowledgment process I'm doing is not necessary when using tcp, and that tcp already does that for you; but isn't the handshake only done once per connection? What if I don't close the connection between the two? Then only one handshake at the creation of the connection would have happened.

Do I have to create a new connection every time I want to be sending something? And isn't the handshake done **before** the data is sent, and only when making the connection? So this might not be what I'm looking for in my case.

Comment: Go ahead and send the message size as part of the protocol. It's the standard approach for implementing a protocol over TCP/IP.   TCP/IP acknowledgments are per-PACKET, not per connection.  You can certainly design your protocol to support multiple requests/replies using a single connection.

Comment: "what if the client machine bugged and it sent an incorrect size" - what if it bugged and sent completely random data?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I know I'm really confused on what I should be doing

Comment: The point is that you may as well assume that the client end is behaving, because there's nothing sensible you can do if it isn't.  You could implement a timeout if you wanted, but if you're only ever dealing with a single client, there's not all that much point.